# Computed columns sometimes missing from SELECT *

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

In SQL Azure, I have a table more or less set up like this, with two computed columns (`IsExpired` and `IsDeadlineExpired`) that simply compare non-nullable datetime columns to the current time:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stuff]
(
   [StuffId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
   [Guid] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
   [ExpirationDate] datetime NOT NULL,
   [DeadlineDate] datetime NOT NULL,
   [UserId] int NOT NULL,
   [IsExpired] AS CAST((CASE WHEN [ExpirationDate] < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit),
   [IsDeadlineExpired] AS CAST((CASE WHEN [DeadlineDate] < GETUTCDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit),
   CONSTRAINT [PK_StuffId] PRIMARY KEY ([StuffId]),
   CONSTRAINT [UNQ_Guid] UNIQUE([Guid]),
)
GO
```

I have a stored procedure with several result sets, one of which pulls:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Stuff] WHERE [Guid] = @guid
```

I've recently noticed error logs indicating that sometimes when the result set is read with `SqlDataReader`, `SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("IsExpired")` fails with `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I know the preceding columns work fine even in those cases, since they're read in preceding lines of code with no errors. I also believe the result sets from the procedure are in proper sequence since they don't share column names (otherwise reading the earlier columns would similarly fail).

Also: most of the time everything seems to work perfectly.

Can this somehow be attributed to Azure transient faults?

Comment: And yet another reason supporting my choice to never use `*`

Comment: I agree, reworking it to select explicit columns would be preferable and would probably make it work 100%, but I never expected `*` to behave like this. I mainly posted it because it's such a noodle-scratcher.

Comment: Yeah it is rather odd. Were those columns added after the fact?

Comment: No; those columns were added to our table definition scripts long before we first deployed to this database.

Comment: Do you still get the error if the computed columns are persisted?

Comment: Have you tried to insert new data using stored procedure, instead using computing columns? Alter table and remove computed columns, use sp, then check if SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal() works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at some old logs, settled on the conclusion that this error was only happening when the queries were running while a DACPAC was concurrently being deployed (as part of our automated deployments to this particular test environment).

I assume that the schema is not necessarily in a dependable state during DACPAC deployment.

Since then, we've added some code to put the app into a "maintenance mode" during deployments, (even these automated ones). This seems to mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer this article: [SELECT * AND SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/10/10009232.aspx).

Its author strongly recommend to replace

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
```

with

```
SELECT [Column1], [Column2], ... [ColumnN]
FROM TableName
```

because ***Using SELECT * can cause extra paging, RFID lookups, unneeded table locking and hinders any future attempts to create a covered index. In summary, it is bad for performance***.

By The Way: here you've got a set of interesting articles:

1. [How to get to SQL Azure Query Performance Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2011/12/15/how-to-get-to-sql-azure-query-performance-data.aspx)
2. [Query Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190610%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
3. [Getting Started with the Windows Azure Tools for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff687127.aspx)
4. [Getting Started with SQL Azure Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309175.aspx)
5. [Improving Your I/O Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/27/10043069.aspx)
6. [Analyzing Query Performance just got easier with SQL Azure.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2010/02/20/analyzing-query-performance-just-got-easier-with-sql-azure.aspx)

I suspect that **GetOrdinary("IsExpired")** causes [System.IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3zwz4dx3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) because of above behaviour of MS SQL Azure framework.

Conclusion? Use **SELECT** statement with defined list of columns to improve performance of SQL Azure database and avoid IndexOutOfRange exception.